# Redirect user to page while sending custom IP adress with post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I was wondering if it would be possible to send a custom IP adress to a target URL redirect.

For example, if I use `header("Location: https://asite.com/stuff")`, how can I input some setting to let the website know what the user's IP adress is (I want it to always be 199.99.9.9).

This because I don't want the target site to know the IP adress of the visitor to prevent the site from automatically filling in data based on previous visits. The site I send the user to connects the IP adress to the mobile number entered in a field when the site is visited through mobile. What I want is the user having to fill in his mobile number on each visit, by setting the IP adress as the one my server has (not being a mobile device, thus the website doesn't connect the IP adress to the mobile phone number).

Is there some way using PHP, Ajax, JQuery or anything else to achieve this?

EDIT: The target site is not my site. Some details need to be entered there but it saves the phone number if the browser is from a mobile device. The point is that users of the phone can let others fill in their mobile phone number (it's a payment site my site uses). So I don't have any influence on what is going on on that site, the only thing I can think of right now is to set the visitors IP adress to a custom one (so the target website gets tricked and doesn't save the phone number for my IP adress).

Comment: What? How do you plan to set an IP address with `header()`? That is simply sending back data to the client in the response. Are you referring to headers sent to the server from the client?

Comment: You'll need a proxy for that, if you write with a fake source you won't be able to receive confirmation packets.

Comment: @Louis I need an alternative to achieve this. But I don't know how. I redirect the user to an URL but I want to let the target website know what the IP adress is.

Comment: @CharlesForest I don't think I need a confirmation since it's a redirect anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent auto-fill, salt the field names with a session ID.

`<input name="email">` becomes `<input name="email_478234723984">`, then the browser will not recognize it as the same form.

Comment: The target site is not my site. Some details need to be entered there but it saves the phone number if the browser is from a mobile device. The point is that users of the phone can let others fill in their mobile phone number (it's a payment site my site uses). So I don't have any influence on what is going on on that site, the only thing I can think of right now is to set the visitors IP adress to a custom one (so the target website gets tricked and doesn't save the phone number for my IP adress).

Comment: That would be a possible attack vector, so it is unlikely to work.

Comment: The target site won't check for it. Besides if it would work or not, do you think this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Populate a form with PHP and send it with JavaScript.

HTML / PHP:

```
<form action="http://google.com/" method="POST" id="form">
    <input type="text" name="ip" value="<?php echo $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]; ?>"/>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("form").submit();
```